# How to get to this cannon in New Super Mario Bros 2?

Tags: new-super-mario-bros-2

I'm in World 3 of New Super Mario Bros 2 on 3DS. There is a cannon (see image below) which I assume will take me to the second special world. But I have tried every level around it and cannot find any secret exits.

[image: mario]

How do I get to the cannon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown in this video (from 1:04)

In the tower as mini mario take the tiny pipe just before the half way point, and follow that branch.